# How to read Install Directory from MSI when no directory named as "INSTALLDIR", "INSTALLDIRECTORY" in Directory table

Tags: c#, wix, windows-installer

I want to read Install Directory of a MSI. I am able to read Install directory when Install directory is specified by "INSTALLDIR", "INSTALLDIRECTORY" or "INSTALLLOCATION" in Directory table. But many msis doesn't contain "INSTALLDIR" or so. Then how to determine what is the install directory of particular msi.

Is there any specific list of keywords which could be used to specify Install directory, as some msi contain INSTALLDIR, some contain INSTALLDIRECTORY or some contain INSTALLLOCATION.

I am using following code snipet to get install directory

```
                DataTable directoryTable;

            directoryTable = this.ReadMsiTableByName(msiFile, "Directory");     // get Directory table of msi specifiec bt msiFile.



            foreach (DataRow row in directoryTable.Rows)
            {
                if (row["Directory"].ToString() == "INSTALLLOCATION" || row["Directory"].ToString() == "INSTALLDIR" || row["Directory"].ToString() == "INSTALLDIRECTORY")
                {
                    installDirectoryPath = row["Directory_Parent"].ToString();
                    break;
                }
            }

            string directory = installDirectoryPath;
            while (directory != "TARGETDIR")
            {
                foreach (DataRow row in directoryTable.Rows)
                {
                    if (row["Directory"].ToString() == directory)
                    {
                        installDirectoryPath = row["Directory_Parent"].ToString() + "//" + installDirectoryPath;

                        directory = row["Directory_Parent"].ToString();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Please advise how to get Install directory of MSI if INSTALLDIR entry is not in Directory table. I am writing code in C# and using WiX dlls.

Answer (score 2):

Because "INSTALLDIR", "INSTALLDIRECTORY" or "INSTALLLOCATION" are not [standard Windows Installer properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/En-US/Library/Windows/Desktop/c91119b9-59d5-4a33-91cd-d3ba63659d12) there can be no guarantee that they will exist in every msi installation.

The [TARGETDIR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/En-US/Library/Windows/Desktop/279bb9ad-afb6-406e-b74a-8424da177e6f) property specifies the root destination directory for the installation. TARGETDIR must be the name of one root in the Directory table. There may be only a single root destination directory.

If the TARGETDIR property is defined, the destination directory is resolved to the property's value. If the TARGETDIR property is undefined, the ROOTDRIVE property is used to resolve the path.

The [ROOTDRIVE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/En-US/Library/Windows/Desktop/aa371372) property specifies the default drive for the destination directory of the installation. If ROOTDRIVE is not set at a command line or authored into the Property table, the installer sets this property.

In the MSDN documentation see

[Directory Table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/En-US/Library/Windows/Desktop/aa368295)

[Using the Directory Table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/En-US/Library/Windows/Desktop/aa372452)

[Specifying Directory Structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/En-US/Library/Windows/Desktop/31390138-b1d0-4f0b-9304-6e7c69e6a736)

[Changing the Target Location for a Directory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/En-US/Library/Windows/Desktop/aa367852)